# How to use formencode for textarea with multi rows

Tags: python, formencode

my code:

> ```
> name = validators.UnicodeString(not_empty=True)
> slug = validators.UnicodeString()
> condition = validators.OneOf(ItemConditionList(), missing=None)
> desc = validators.UnicodeString(input_tag="textarea")
> ```

my web:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlFP8.png

my question:
I want the "Desc" field with default 20 rows. 
I try with formencode 's document but i can't.
Please help me!
Thank you!

UPDATE
Sorry, my question perhaps because i use package "pyramid_auto_hq" (auth: tarzanjw)at: https://github.com/tarzanjw/pyramid_auto_hq/blob/master/lib/bootstrap_renderer/horizontal/smart_input_row.py

what should i do? contact to Mr.Taranjw or any ideas?